# Is there a way to use node js with karate ZIP edition

Tags: karate

I'm looking for way to use npm packages for writing javascript functions for my requirement.
I have tried using imports and require for the same in external js files but no luck with it. Can someone suggest me a way in which we can achieve that?

Comment: we expect this to be possible once we move to GraalVM, but it may take 6 months to get there

Comment: @PeterThomas so can we maintain a separate code base where we incorporate the node js and then through some way call those functions from the feature file in the karate zip edition.

Comment: yes, but it is up to you how to make the connection. maybe calling via command line or as a REST service